# How to check for duplicate entries before inserting any data? I am using Visual Basic.Net and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Here is my code using stored procedure in visual basic.net:

```
Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand()

sqlComm.Connection = sqlCon
sqlComm.CommandText = "InsertDataIntoTable"
sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", txtname.Text)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", txtsurname.Text)
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", Integer.Parse(txtage.Text))

sqlCon.Open()
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
sqlCon.Close()
```

Stored procedure code using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I tried to insert

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblSPExample WHERE Name= @Name) < 1
```

before then begin keyword but my problem is it can't prompt message in visual basic there is a duplicate name that already exists in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataIntoTable]
   @Name varchar(50),
   @Surname varchar(50),
   @Age int
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tblSPExample(Name, Surname, Age)
   VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Age)
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this in your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataIntoTable]
@Name varchar(50),
@Surname varchar(50),
@Age int 
AS

BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblSPExample WHERE Name = @Name and Surname = @Surname and Age = @Age)
   INSERT INTO tblSPExample(Name, Surname, Age)
   VALUES ( @Name, @Surname, @Age)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IF NOT EXISTS()` answer provided by @R.T. - that's much more efficient than your `SELECT COUNT(*) .... > 0` approach!

In order to find out in your VB.NET code whether something has been inserted, check out the **return value** from the `ExecuteNonQuery` call:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and **returns the number of rows affected**.

So if you check for this being `> 0`, you know a row has been inserted; if it is `= 0` then no row has been inserted:

```
int rowsInserted = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (rowsInserted <= 0)   // no rows were inserted
   MessageBox.Show("No rows inserted");   // or whatever you want to do ....
```